# java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported with OPEN_READONLY

Tags: android, android-sqlite

On trying to open sqlite db with the below statement 
db=openOrCreateDatabase(dbname,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY,null);

I am gettng the below error

> java.lang.SecurityException: MODE_WORLD_READABLE no longer supported

But if I try to open db with **OPEN_READWRITE** its opening.

Could you please help me how to open the db with Read only mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing the integer flags.

You're calling [`openOrCreateDatabase()` method in `Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)). That method does not take in `SQLiteDatabase` flags but `Context` flags. The flags get interpreted differently and when your target SDK is Nougat or higher, you get this exception.

There's [`openDatabase()` static method in `SQLiteDatabase`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)) that takes in flags such as `SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY`.

Consider using [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) though. It makes your database management easier, and you can just call `getReadableDatabase()` to indicate you want a read-only database.

Comment: Thanks you. Worked for  me

Answer (score 0):

World-readable files can be a security flaw. So google first deprecated it and then completely removed it. 
 `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`

was deprecated in versions till **Android M**. But in **Android N** it is no longer supported and throws SecurityException.

So As the error indicates, `

> MODE_WORLD_READABLE is not supported

`. Remove that flag from your`getSharedPreferences()`call, replacing it with`MODE_PRIVATE or 0.`

Comment: OP does not have that flag explicitly nor is calling `getSharedPreferences()`